# What do you call a person who writes letters?

Tags: nouns, personal-pronouns, letter-writing

I found, from my search, that [*epistolary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epistolary) is an adjective which could refer to the writing of letters.  But is there noun of this to call someone who writes letters?

Comment: You could call such a person _epistoler._

Comment: @user405662 I was wondering if there was a derivative word from *epistolary* but was unsure, thank you!  Could you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call such a person an **epistoler.**

> epistoler, literary: A letter-writer; = epistler
>
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/epistoler)

**Epistolist** is another word for a letter-writer.

> Someone who writes epistles
>
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epistolist)